# Ignore MVC components when executing @DataJpaTest(s) with SpringRunner.class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Given the following:
(as you can see I am trying **in vain** to ignore all the services and components - I would actually just like to remove all the MVC and security components when running `DataJpaTest` tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest(
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, 
                classes = { org.springframework.stereotype.Service.class, org.springframework.stereotype.Component.class }))
public class SpringLearningExcerciseTest extends TestCase {

    @Inject
    Repository repo;

    @Test
    public void givenStuffThenOtherStuffIsTrue() {
        repo.save(...);
    }
```

> 'userRequestContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'requestServlet'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest'

I don't need all the request MVC / Serverlet stuff loaded for a repository test.
How do I ignore all those.

The shortcut is to just use `SpringBootTest` which works just fine, but it seems heavy handed.
I would prefer to actually have all the services and components intact, but no controllers or MVC stuff loaded. Better still, have just what I need loaded.

Comment: I didn't try this, but it looks like you could annotate the class with:
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude= WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class)

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html 
@DataJpaTest should not load any stuff related to servlets. It should load only configuration relevant to JPA tests.
Are you sure that you receive error from this test? What is in your class "TestCase"?

Comment: I tried to exclude WebMvcAutoConfiguration, same issue.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRequestContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'requestServlet'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}